# AVAssetTrack Combine video not okay in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, ios6, record

I can successfully combine 2 video into 1 in iOS 6. But I don't know what happen in iOS 7. I got array error like this.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'**

This is part of the code I write. I have shown where error in the code. How should I do?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

for(int kk=0;kk < trackRecordingVideoName+1; kk++)
{
    [array addObject:[[self userPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.mp4",recordingVideoName,kk]]];
    NSLog(@"%d is added",kk);
}

videoPathArray= [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:array];
[videoPathArray retain];


AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];


CMTime startTime = kCMTimeZero;


NSLog(@"videoPathArray.count is %d",videoPathArray.count);
for (NSInteger i=0; i < videoPathArray.count; i++) {

    NSLog(@"For loop now is %d and name is %@",i,[videoPathArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSString *path = (NSString*)[videoPathArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

    [url release];

    //*************************************
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];//This is the error
    //*************************************


    if(i == 0)
    {
        [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:videoTrack.preferredTransform];
    }

    Boolean ok = [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:startTime error:nil];

    if(ok)
    {NSLog(@"can combine in for loop");}
    else{NSLog(@"cannot combine in for loop");}

    startTime = CMTimeAdd(startTime, [asset duration]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `url` if its wright, it should point to a real video file, your `AVURLAsset` don't contain any video media type.